# Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, netbeans

i want to use javascript array globly using netbeans ide..
i declare the array like this.layer=new Array(); and var layer=new Array(); but the problem is that when i use the array in function  the drop down menu of Array functions is not shown as netbeans shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type analysis for a fully-dynamic language like JavaScript is tricky and there's no guarantee an IDE will be able to resolve it. Autocompletion is very much a best-guess feature. I wouldn't expect tracking properties like `this.layer` to work as, unless it enforces one particular style of object creation there is no way for an IDE to know what `this` is.

I would suggest in general using the array literal syntax `[]` in preference to `new Array` in almost every case. Don't know if that'll help Netbeans though.

Comment: `[]` instead of `new Array` is highly recommended for JavaScript.